# http-request gives "Message payload is of type"

Tags: mule

I have a flow that needs to call an external API call in within but it keeps giving me the exception message `Message payload is of type: ...`. I'm using 3.6.2 right now.

```
<http:request-config name="ApiRest" protocol="HTTPS"   doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" basePath="rest" host="${api.endpointUrl}" port="80">
    <oauth2:client-credentials-grant-type clientId="${api.client_id}" clientSecret="${api.client_secret}">
        <oauth2:token-request tokenUrl="${api.endpointUrl}/oauth/token" />
    </oauth2:client-credentials-grant-type>
</http:request-config>
<flow name="flow-1">
    // more components here...
    <http:request config-ref="ApiRest" path="/v1/users" method="GET" sendBodyMode="NEVER" doc:name="test">
        <http:request-builder/>
    </http:request>
</flow>
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using HTTPS but have 80 as port: it should be 443. To get more help you should add the entire stack trace of the exception you are seeing to this question. HTH.

Comment: @afelisatti my goodness, you're right... how could I forget... Thanks! you should put that as an answer :)

Comment: Great! Added it as answer so we can mark this as solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that HTTPS works with port 443, not 80. That should do it.